# Magento 2 change pdf filename

Tags: pdf, filenames, magento2

I want to change the filenames of the PDF files in Magento 2.

The default names are not clear and I want invoices to be searchable when saved to a location on my pc.

Is it possible to change the filenames of the PDF-files in Magento 2 to a format like "invoice_1000000123.pdf"?

Answer (score 0):

You should **never** edit core files. Seriously, don't.

Since `/vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Invoice/AbstractInvoice/PrintAction.php` is an abstract class you have to use a plugin or preference in your module in order to override it.

What you need to achieve that:

The usual minimum files: 
`/Vendor/Module/composer.json`, `/Vendor/Module/registration.php`, `/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml`

In `/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml` you should sequence Magento_Sales

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Then you can either use a plugin or a preference in `/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Invoice\AbstractInvoice\PrintAction" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Invoice\AbstractInvoice\PrintAction"/>      
</config>
```

Plugin would look something like this:

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Invoice\AbstractInvoice\PrintAction">
    <plugin name="Vendor_Module::aroundPrintInvoice" type="Vendor\Module\Block\Class" sortOrder="0"/>
</type>
```

Now add a `PrintAction.php` to the path specified in your preference / plugin (Example for preference)

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Invoice\AbstractInvoice;

class PrintAction extends \Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Invoice\AbstractInvoice\PrintAction
{
    /* Write code here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need override the invoice admin controller.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice" 
      type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice" />
</config>
```

In your custom module admin controller, You need to change the name of Pdf file.

```
public function execute() 
{
  $invoiceId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('invoice_id');
  return $this->_fileFactory->create(
                    'invoice_13012020' . $invoiceId . '.pdf', //<== Change the pdf name here.
                    $pdf->render(),
                    DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
                    'application/pdf'
                );
        ...
    }
```

[Reference Link](http://magelara.com/how-to-change-invoice-pdf-name-in-magento-2/)

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is possible to change invoice pdf filename.

Please go to following path:

```
/vendor/magento/module-sales/Controller/Adminhtml/Invoice/AbstractInvoice/PrintAction.php
```

You can change filename from above file.